# Selenium can not locate sign in button for amazon.com

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("nav-action-button"));  
         Actions actions = new Actions(driver);  
         try {  
             JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
          js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);  
           actions.moveToElement(element).perform();  
           actions.click(element).perform();  
         } catch (Exception e) {  
          // throw new TestException(String.format("The following element is not clickable: [%s]", element.toString()));  
         }
```

I have also tried

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("nav-your-amazon"));  
         Actions actions = new Actions(driver);  
         try {  
             JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
          js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);  
           actions.moveToElement(element).perform();  
           actions.click(element).perform();  
         } catch (Exception e) {  
          // throw new TestException(String.format("The following element is not clickable: [%s]", element.toString()));  
         }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please edit your post to add the error you are receiving

Answer (score 4):

Just try with different locator type-

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='nav-link-yourAccount']/span[1]"));
```

OR:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Hello. Sign in')]"));
```

OR:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'nav-line-1')]"));
```

Followed by adding the same code of **Action class**.

[image]

Comment: The different suggested locators still do not work, there is no error message but the button is not clicked. I get below error though2017-04-17 07:59:39.044 plugin-container[1917:156853] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x933b, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.

Comment: You can try without using Action class. Use direct   element.click()  method.